# How do I license my Excel VBA through internet?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, vba

I am developing a VBA macro in Excel. 
I want it to be locked or licensed for each machine or user that uses it.

I am thinking of doing it through an internet lookup. Maybe something to download the VBA script from MySQL if the user has access.

Does anybody have any ideas or has worked on something like this before?

I have been looking for solutions through Google but I haven't found any strong ideas.

Comment: Please add more detail, like is it free? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [FAQ], it is expected that questions address some specific programming problem. It sounds like you need an entire system to manage download access.

Comment: @RyanB if its free then why would he care?

Comment: @Ap tracking? I am not sure. If he wants people to pay, he could use PayPal or something to develop an id.

Comment: I want to get payed. Specifically a company to pay for each license. Maybe make free for a while, like 2 months for testing.But after that I would like to get money for it.

Comment: I dont want a entiry sistem to download. Only maybe a small function to check for license status. And then update VBA code inside of Excel downloaded from MySql. Just an Idea. If you have other better, please let us know.

Answer (score 2):

Its fairly easy to control the download or install, but once downloaded and installed the protection for VBA is weak and easily bypassed: so its difficult to protect against people copying and reinstalling the VBA code. Compiled VB6 is inherently much more secure, but is sadly obsolete.

Comment: Consider developing an Excel plug-in instead.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but, I want to serch thru all options and don't give up easily. I want to continue with the VBA project and if the company wants to upgrade more fuctions to the project they wil have to call me. Or pay for VBA code access privilegies.